# Problems with Vector to Vector String Comparison Search

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, find, compare

I have an algorithm that's supposed to compare the strings in two separate vectors and compare the content of the first vector file : fileContent with fileContent1. If there is a string match the program should print out each line of the first Vector and report if there is a line in vector two that matches (if this is the case print out "YES:" Vector1 line or "No" Vector1 line) at the moment my output is this and I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Any tips or help would be appreciated.

My output at the moment:

```
NO:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:altimbankery
YES:loessoid
NO:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:loessoid
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
NO:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:stampede
YES:soger
YES:soger
YES:soger
NO:soger
YES:soger
YES:soger
YES:soger
YES:soger
YES:soger
YES:soger
YES:soger
YES:soger
YES:soger
YES:soger
YES:soger
YES:soger
YES:soger
YES:soger
YES:soger
YES:soger
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
NO:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:Plutarchical
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
NO:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:gigglesome
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
NO:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:unheated
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
NO:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:offendress
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
NO:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:syruper
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
NO:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:multispindle
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
NO:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:stinging
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
NO:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:Euspongia
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
NO:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:recluse
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
NO:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:continuum
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
NO:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:promotrix
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
NO:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:menyie
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
NO:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:perpetuator
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
NO:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:hornblower
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:kurung
NO:kurung
YES:kurung
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
YES:inductionally
NO:inductionally
```

Contents of file1:

```
unheated
rheometer
daemonurgy
maltase
morrowless
Plutarchical
czarism
missable
loessoid
siphonozooid
saltimbankery
unreduced
loglike
stampede
clickless
soger
gigglesome
vila
```

Contents of file2:

```
saltimbankery
loessoid
stampede
soger
Plutarchical
gigglesome
unheated
offendress
syruper
multispindle
stinging
Euspongia
recluse
continuum
promotrix
menyie
perpetuator
hornblower
kurung
inductionally
```

Algorithm:

```
if(algo_speed == "slow")
{
    i = 0;

    while(getline(ifs1, line))
    {
        fileContent1.push_back(line);
        fileContent.push_back(line);
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < fileContent1.size() ; i++)
    {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < fileContent.size() ; j++)
        {
            size_t found = fileContent[i].find(fileContent1[j]);
            if(found) {
                cout << "YES:" << fileContent.at(i) << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "NO:" << fileContent.at(i) << endl;
            }

            //sort(fileContent1.begin(), fileContent1.end());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you really expecting someone will read THAT output? LOL

Comment: You're counting `i` from 0 to `fileContent1.size()` but use it as an index into `fileContent`. Use proper variable names to prevent these errors. `std::string::find` returns `npos` if it doesn't find a match. This will usually convert to `true`, not `false`. Likewise, if it finds a match at the beginning of the sequence, it will return 0, implicitly converted to `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not completely clear.  I understand it that you want a single line of output for each word in the first file.  In that case, you are doing the output stage inside the wrong loop.  You should do it in the outer loop, not the inner one.  For the inner loop, you just loop until found.

The other problem you have is expecting `string::find` to return a boolean.  This is not true.  It returns an index, or `string::npos` if not found.  You could have used the string equality operator instead.

So, using the above recommendations, your code becomes:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < fileContent.size() ; i++)
{
    bool found = false;
    for(size_t j = 0; j < fileContent1.size() && !found; j++)
    {
        found = fileContent[i] == fileContent1[j];
    }

    if(found) {
        cout << "YES:" << fileContent.at(i) << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "NO:" << fileContent.at(i) << endl;
    }
}
```

Of course, you can avoid the inner loop altogether if you use `std::find` on the vector.

```
bool found = std::find(fileContent1.begin(), fileContent1.end(), fileContent[i]) != fileContent1.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::find` on your vector 2.
You should soleve this easily

```
std::for_each(vector1.cbegin(),vector1.cend(), [&](const std::string &s)->void{
    auto it=std::find_if(vector2.cbegin(),vector2.cend(), 
        [&](const std::string & s2)-> bool{
        return s2==s1;
    }
    std::cout<<(it==vector2.cend() ? "NO ":"YES "<<s;
}
```